# Golang convert type [N]byte to []byte

Tags: go, slice

I have this code:

```
hashChannel <- []byte(md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes()))
```

And I get this error:

```
cannot convert md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes()) (type [16]byte) to type []byte
```

Even without the explicit conversion this does not work. I can keep the type [16]byte as well, but at some point I need to convert it, as I'm sending it over a TCP connection:

```
_, _ = conn.Write(h)
```

What is the best method to convert it?
Thanks

Comment: `[:]` converts an array to a slice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Slice the array. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var hashChannel = make(chan []byte, 1)
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    sum := md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes())
    hashChannel <- sum[:]
    fmt.Println(<-hashChannel)
}
```

Output:

```
[212 29 140 217 143 0 178 4 233 128 9 152 236 248 66 126]
```

Answer (score 8):

Creating a slice using an array you can just make a [`simple slice expression`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

```
foo := [5]byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
var bar []byte = foo[:]
```

Or in your case:

```
b := md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes())
hashChannel <- b[:]
```

Comment: BUG: `hashChannel <- md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes())[:]` error is  `invalid operation md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes())[:] (slice of unaddressable value)`

Comment: peterSo: Ah, yes. Sorry for that. Bug indeed. Corrected it

Comment: @ANisus Do you know why we need to introduce an intermediary variable `b` rather than just using `hashChannel <- md5.Sum(buffer.Bytes())[:]` for instance?

Comment: @boramalper The specification for the slice expression states that "If the sliced operand is an array, it must be addressable.". Which in this case means an *array variable* or a *pointer indirection* to the array. I can't answer exactly as to why they made that choice.